# Natural numbers for set of polymonials

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, polynomials

I'm working on the following problem and have made it through everything but the final step.  I'm not sure how to show that each of my subsets are distinct, maybe I'm missing something here or maybe my approach is just wrong.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Problem:

Let z be an integer and $f(t) = a_nt^n + ... + a_1t + a_0$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients. Then there is a unique way to write $f(t)$ in the form $b_n(t - z)^n + ... + b_1(t - z) + b_0$. For instance, if $z = 3$ and $f(t) = t^2 + 4t − 1$, then $f(t) = (t - 3)^2 + 10(t - 3) + 20$. So in this example $b_2 = 1$, $b_1 = 10$ and $b_0 = 20$.  Use this fact to construct infinitely many different subsets N of polynomials with integer coefficients which satisfy the following properties (natural numbers):

i)  If m,n ∈ N then m+n ∈ N

ii)  If m,n ∈ N then mn ∈ N

iii)  0 $\notin$ N

iv)  For every m ∈ Z, we have m ∈ N or m = 0 or −m ∈ N

My attempt at a solution:

Let $A_k$ where k is an integer be a subset of the polynomials with integer coefficients such that the elements of $A_k$ are the polynomials that when written uniquely in the form $b_n(t - k)^n + ... + b_1(t - k) + b_0$ have a leading coefficient $b_n > 0$.

First we will show that $A_k$ satisfies the desired properties

(i) If $m,n \in A_k$ then $ m+n \in A_k$:  Let $b_m$ be the leading coefficient of element m and $b_n$ be the leading coefficient of element n when written in the form given above.  Then in case 1: m is of higher degree than n.  Then the leading coefficient of m+n is $b_m$ which we know is $>$ 0 since $m \in A_k$.  In case 2: n is of higher degree than m.  Then the leading coefficient of m+n is $b_n$ which we know is $>$ 0 since $n \in A_k$.  And in case 3: n is of the same degree as m.  Then the leading coefficient of m+n is $b_n + b_m$ which we know is $>$ 0 since $n \in A_k$ and $m \in A_k$.

(ii) If $m,n \in A_k$ then $mn \in A_k$:  Let $b_m$ be the leading coefficient of element m and $b_n$ be the leading coefficient of element n when written in the form given above.  Then the leading coefficient of m+n is $(b_m)(b_n)$ which we know is $>$ 0 since $m \in A_k$ and $n \in A_k$.

(iii) $0 \notin A_k$:  The zero polynomial has a leading coefficient $b_n = 0 \ngtr 0$.  So $0 \notin A_k$.

(iv) For every $m \in Z$, we have $m \in A_k$ or $m = 0$ or $−m \in A_k$:  Let $m \in Z$.  Suppose (iv) does not hold.  Since $m \notin A_k$, we know that $b_m \leq 0$.  So $b_m = 0$ or $b_m < 0$.  Since we assumed (iv) does not hold, we must have $b_m < 0$.  So $0 - b_m \in N$, which gives us $-b_m \in N$, so $-b_m > 0$.  Since the leading coefficient of $-m$ is $-b_m$, $-m \in A_k$.  This is a contradiction since we assumed (iv) does not hold.  So (iv) does hold for $A_k$.

Now we will show that there are infinitely many subsets $A_k$.  Since k is any integer, we can get infinitely many $A_k$s by varying k since Z is an infinite set.

All that remains is to show that each subset $A_k$ is different for different k.  This is where I'm stuck but I'm pretty sure that it's possible to show this.  Would appreciate any help on this, thanks!

Update: still stuck, but I think the approach is correct. any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure now that my approach is correct, just can't quite manage to get this last step.  Any ideas?